# g++ environment problem : This program can only run in D: \ s MinGW \ bin (the folder where g++is located), and cannot run outside this folder

Tags: c++, c++17, g++, mingw-w64

This program can only run in D: \ s MinGW \ bin (the folder where g++is located), and cannot run outside this folder.

a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    // C++17 std::variant 使用
    std::variant<int, std::string> value;
    value = 42;
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << '\n'; }, value);

    value = "Hello, World!";
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << '\n'; }, value);

    // C++17 std::optional 使用
    std::optional<int> maybeNumber;
    maybeNumber = 3.14; // 注意：自动转换为整数
    if (maybeNumber)
        std::cout << "Optional contains: " << *maybeNumber << '\n';

    // C++17 std::string_view 使用
    std::string str{"Test String"};
    std::string_view view{str};
    std::cout << "String View: " << view << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

[The program can run normally in this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcMBg.png)

[The program can run normally in this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aPiW.png)

[The program cannot run properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE8NG.png)

D: \ s MinGW \ bin has been correctly configured in the environment variables

Do you need to add anything on Windows?
Why can it only run in that folder?
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: g++ (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-Builds project) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: The classic case of DLL mismatch. Move `C:\MinGW\bin` up to be the first entry in the PATH, so DLLs from it get priority over the ones with the same names you have elsewhere. Or figure out what DLLs your program needs from this directory, and copy them next to the .exe (will need to do this sooner or later to distribute your app). `ntldd -R my_app.exe` from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) will give you the list of required DLLs.